# Gauss's mean value theorem problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that  $f(z)$ is analytic and $f(z)\neq0$  on the disc $|z|<1$ .

Show that for $0<r<1$,

$$
\exp\left[\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\log}|f(re^{i\theta})|\,d\theta\right] = |f(0)|
$$

Any other theorems needed to solve this problem?
I don't have any idea just with "Gauss's MVT"

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint: you can rewrite the equality as $$\frac 1{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \log |f(re^{i\theta})| \, d\theta = \log |f(0)|$$ or even just $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} g(re^{i\theta}) \, d\theta = g(0)$$ if you define $g(z) = \log |f(z)|$. If $f$ is analytic and nonvanishing then $g$ is harmonic.

Comment: If g is harmonic, can I apply Gauss's MVT on g?

Comment: Yes, that is the right idea

Comment: @UmbertoP. If $f$ is non-zero on the interval, then the $\log(|f|)$ won't have any pole. Then the integral is $\oint\limits_{C_r} \log(|f(z)|) dz$, where $C_r$ is the circle with radius $r$. But without poles inside, the countour integral will be $0$, and $\exp(0)=1$. What did I miss out?

Comment: $\log |f(z)|$ is real-valued and thus definitely not analytic. It is harmonic.

Comment: @UmbertoP. can you who are more professional fix the wiki error by stating ".. the harmonic functions are real analogues to holomorphic functions. All harmonic functions are analytic, that is, they can be locally expressed as power series." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Jensen's formula : 
If f(z) is analytic on the disc $|z| <r $ apart from roots at a1,a2,...,am (repeated by multiplicity) and $f(0) \neq 0 $ then :

$\frac{1}{2 \pi }\int_0^{2\pi} \ln |f(re^{i\theta})|d\theta + \sum_{k=1}^{m} \ln (\frac{|a_k|}{r}) = \ln |f(0)| $

In your case, there are no zeros so you get

$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\log}\left|f(re^{i\theta})\right|\mathrm d\theta=ln|f(0)|$